# Facebook Pixel pageview initialisation on AJAX (SPA)

Tags: analytics, facebook-pixel

I have a website, based on Single Page Application (SPA) technology. So, while users navigate through website, the page is not reloaded.

At the time, I initialise Facebook Pixel via GTM on each new page, but document.location doesn't change in that case, so I send 'pageview' with incorrect address and title.
I'd like FB Pixel to know correct new page path, but there are no instructions to send a pageview event with manually set parameters, like

`ga('send', 'pageview', [page], [fieldsObject]);`

Has anyone solved that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You can set the custom parameters with ga script. 
Send it like.. I am using below script after ga create.

```
<script>ga('send', 'pagename', 'pagetitle','pagesection','moretags');</script>
```

Comment: @Anton Use the other ga script line again, not try to send always with pageview

Comment: thx for the answer, but did you actually read the question? I know how GA & its events work, the tread is about Facebook pixel.